# Passing params or get params directly in method body

Tags: php, dependency-injection

For example:

Case 1: Passing parameters through method

```
protected function _arrange_data($data, $sort) { ... }
```

Case 2: Get parameters in the method body

```
$this->_set_datas($data);
$this->_set_sort($sort);

protected function _arrange_data() {
    $datas = $this->_get_datas();
    $sort  = $this->_get_sort();
}
```

Case 1: It look a little messy when a method need 4, 5 parameters. You need to get necessary data before call the method

Case 2: It look more clearly and no need to do anythings before call the method because method will get parameters itself. But I think this case will break "Dependency Injection" principle because it's not loose coupling and hard to maintenance

Question: Which solution do you prefer? Or if you have another way, please tell me.
I am all ears.

Comment: If you can do the second approach (i.e. the method soley works on a part of the state[/data] of the object) you _can_ consider a third option: encapsulate that data in another class with methods working on _its_ state. But the question as stated is hard to answer.

Comment: If either of the two approaches was correct in all situations, we wouldn't have the option to choose between them. It's not possible to answer this question.

Comment: @VolkerK could you please give me more detail or tutorial about "third option"

Comment: hm, maybe e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance